# How to skip "Access Denied" Folder when zip folder with command-line?

Tags: command-line, zip, backup, winrar

I have a batch file to copy data between 2 Disk below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ag E:\Backup C:\NeedBackup -ms
```

Maybe use Winrar or 7-zip but they cannot copy folder with Deny for all permission. I want to skip that folder and continue to copy other files.
Anyone help me???

Comment: *WinRAR* and *7-Zip*  are compression tools and not directory/file copying tools.

Comment: Yes, I see. I use WinRar and 7-Zip to backup my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start *WinRAR* and click in menu **Help** on **Help topics**. On tab **Contents** open list item **Command line mode**. Read first the help page *Command line syntax*.

Next open sublist item **Switches** and click on item *Alphabetic switches list*. While reading the list of available switches for GUI version of *WinRAR* build the command line.

For example:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ac -agYYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -ep1 -ibck -inul E:\Backup C:\NeedBackup\
```

**Note 1:** Switch `-inul` implicitly enables `-y` which is not documented but I know from author of *WinRAR* and my own tests.

You might use also the switch `-dh` although I recommend not using it for this backup operation.

By using additionally switch `-ao` the created backup archive would contain only files with having currently archive attribute set. This means only files added/modified since last backup are added to new archive because of usage of switch `-ac` in previous backup operation, i.e. creating incremental backup archives instead of always complete backups.

Well, the switch `-df` could be also used instead of `-ac` and `-ao` to create incremental backups. *WinRAR* deletes only files which could be 100% successfully compressed into the archive.

For details on those switches read their help pages.

**Note 2:** The command line creates a RAR archive file. For a ZIP file you would need additionally the switch `-afzip`.

**Note 3:** *7-Zip* has also a help file explaining in detail also the usage from command line with all available commands and switches.